# why have we use the inline if else condition in this code how can it filter the element?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms

> what we are using the inline if-else statement in this Django code and what is the use of the name__contains in the code. can someone please answer this question in a basic way? and last what is the use of __ in the django code

```
> def home(request):
>         q = request.GET.get('q') **if request.GET.get('q') != None else ''**
>         rooms = Room.objects.filter(topic__name__contains = q) 
>         topics = Topic.objects.all()
>         context = {'rooms':rooms, 'topics':topics}
>         return render(request,'home.html',context)
```

Answer (score 0):

> what we are using the inline if-else statement in this Django code

```
q = request.GET.get('q') if request.GET.get('q') != None else ''
```

it is checking whether you ***q*** contain any value or not if ***q*** have value it will run further else it will return `''` empty string

> what is the use of the name__contains in the code

It will return the values ​​which will match with your query ***(q)***
see more details about [contains](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#std:fieldlookup-contains)

> what is the use of __ in the django code

it is used for accessing related objects

Comment: Thank you mate for your precious answer can you please answer an another question of mine why we have given empty string in the if else

Comment: Hello @BigyatPokharel it's upon you can remove else part it's just for security reason that if you have not receved any values from client then you probably don't want to send any info to user just return empty string or to be a user friendly return an error